# BlazeDS Streaming Endpoint Tomcat 7 not working

Tags: apache-flex, tomcat7, blazeds

I tried to get Tomcat 7 with BlazeDS to work. It seems that Streaming for Messaging does not work anymore.

I downloaded Tomcat 7 and merged it together with BlazeDS Turnkey samples. If I try ie. the TraderDesktop sample in Safari it falls back to polling. Chrome and Firefox just hangs.

Have somebody already tried it or did I miss something?

Comment: Hi Frank - Did you find any answers to your question? I'm hitting the same issue. Mine worked up to tomcat 7.0.27 though. Please let me know if you have any findings on this.

Comment: Hi Charith, no Streaming with BlazeDS 4 does not work. I checked out BlazeDS and compiled myself. On Tomcat7 with Servlet3 and NIO Streaming Channel can't connect.

Comment: Hi Frank. I can confirm too. I exactly did the same steps. Hope you found this and followed it after http://code.google.com/p/blazeds-servlet3-support/

Comment: Did you find a fix / workaround?

Comment: Future readers follow this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13024000/tomcat-doesnt-do-blazeds-streaming-after-version-7-0-27

Answer (score 0):

As per the cross post, this could be related to your BlazeDS version
Tomcat 7 requires BlazeDS 4 when Tomcat 6.x requires BlazeDS 3

[Source](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/777748)

Comment: No does not work. I checked out latest BlazeDS and compiled it.

Comment: My only experience is with Tomcat 6 / BlazeDS 3. I just know for a fact Tomcat 7 / BlazeDS 3 doesn't work.

Comment: Out of curiosity, did you download from `http://flexorg.wip3.adobe.com/blazeds/4.x/17657/blazeds-turnkey-4.0.1.17657.zip`

Comment: No I downloaded from opensource.adobe.com/svn/opensource/blazeds/trunk. This is what need to be changed in future of Apache Flex. One page with all information and one repository. I will try it with the link you provided...